Why is the date format different from that of my project in recent versions of the mysql net connector?
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture=System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-DO") 
System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern = "dd'/'MM'/'yyyy"

I have these lines of code at the beginning of my application
Public Function BFecha_Servidor() As Boolean
    Using conn = ConexionADO.ObtenerConeccion()
        conn.Open()
        Dim MysqlCommand As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand("SELECT curdate()", conn)
        Fecha_Servidor = MysqlCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString
    End Using
    Return True
End Function

why with mysql net connector 6.9.4 I get the date in "dd/MM/yyyy" format as I have it set in my application, but with mysql net connector 8.0.30 i get the date in "MM/dd/yyyy"?
why is this?
how do i solve it?
I tried to change the collation of the server but it didn't work (although I don't know if I did it right), and now I'm going to try with the lc_time_names variable

Collation is for text, not for dates. I don't think this has anything to do with mysql as in mysql dates are formatted as yyyy-mm-dd. You need to look at cuture settings in your application and in the .net connector.

What exactly does ExecuteScalar return in that case? According to the what I read, that CURDATE function should either return a string in "yyyy-MM-dd" format or a number in yyyyMMdd format.

ExecuteScalar return "18/07/2024" with 6.9.4 connector, "07/18/2024" with 8.0.31 connector

update, the version 8.0.16 still like i want, but in te version 8.0.17 in when the change was applied, y read the version notes, but didn't find anything about it.

If you convert the date to a string in the SQL (I suggest using the yyyy-MM-dd format) then you will have a known place to start from in the VB.NET code. You need to prevent these inconsistencies introduced by a third party from being able to affect your code. Also, MysqlCommand is not a good name for a variable because it is the same (VB is not case-sensitive) as the MySqlCommand method.

@EnmanuelP It's only my opinion, but if the supplier of the database can't keep it working for you and has a vested interest in a paid-for product, maybe it is time to investigate other database suppliers.

The important thing to understand is date values internally do not use a human-readable format at all. Rather, they use a binary format that is efficient for storage/memory use, sorting/indexing, and operations (like adding/subtracting days/hours/months/etc).
Thanks to cultural/internationalization issues, converting between these binary date values and strings is far more complex than you might expect, which makes it a slow and error-prone operation: something to avoid and delay as much as possible.
Therefore, internally, your application should work with typed date/datetime values, rather than strings. You want to convert input to a datetime value as quickly as possible, and keep it there as long as possible. Then, only convert to a string at the last possible moment before showing to a user to exporting to an external system or file, and only worry about the format at this time.
This is relevant because ADO.Net is perfectly happy to give you .Net DateTime values directly from MySQL, regardless of what connector version you use. You should let it do that, and not even worry about the date format on the database.
That is, when you call ExecuteScalar(), do NOT call ToString() on the result. Instead, assign the result to a real DateTime variable (and use DirectCast if you need to). Worry about the format when later outputting the value of the DateTime variable. This will resolve your issue, regardless which connector version is used, as long as MySQL gives you a DateTime column instead of a varchar column.
